# PRIIPs Category 3 - MRM and Performance scenarios

Tags: performance-evaluation, risk-neutral, priips

I almost worked my way through the [CONSOB's PRIIPS workshop](https://www.assoctu.it/fileadmin/AssoCTU/upload/eventi/documenti/DERIVATI_2017/Workshop_Assoctu_241117_Giordano.pdf) workshop and [EMSA's PRIIPS flow diagram](https://www.esma.europa.eu/sites/default/files/library/jc_2017_49_priips_flow_diagram_risk_reward_rev.pdf). Almost. The final missing part for me is the calculation of the standard performance scenarios for a Category 3 fund from the RHP to 1 year.

Similar to the table on page 28 of the ESMA flow diagram (see below), I've calculated the expected values for the recommended holding period of 3 years [RHP = 3] based on the outcomes of the simulations. Now my question: what is the correct way to calculate these values for a 1 year holding period. [image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Many thanks in advance,

Woyzeck